# Como detectar si el cliente pierde la conexion inesperadamente de un socket

Tags: python, socket

Estoy realizando una conexion cliente y servidor mediante socket

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Recibo el siguiente error:**

`socket.error: [Errno 10053] Se ha anulado una conexi¾n establecida por el software en su equipo host`

Se estan enviando los datos correctamente al momento que el cliente cierra la conexion salta la excepcion **el error sucede porque el servidor no es capaz de detectar cuando esta cerrada la conexion por eso ocurre esa excepcion**

**Antes que todo:**

- Recordar que un telefono movil puede apagarse y perder la conexion Wifi

Asi que el servidor de manera obligatoria debe detectar cuando el cliente pierde la conexion de manera inesperada

**Codigo Del Servidor(Python)**

```
import socket  

s = socket.socket()   
s.bind(("192.168.1.94", 60))  
s.listen(1)  #clients permitted connect
print "server run"

sc, addr = s.accept()  

while True:  

      recibido = sc.recv(1024)
      print recibido
      sc.send(recibido)

print "bye"  

sc.close()  
s.close()
```

¿Como le hago para que el servidor de python pueda detectar si un cliente cierra una conexion socket de manera inesperada?

Comment: Quizas ?! estare pensando que utilizar Thread es incorrecto pero a lo mejor puede ser lo correcto porque las comunicaciones siempre se debe realizar en multiprocesos ya que en todo momento se debe verificar los datos recibidos

Comment: Si la aplicacion ejecuta un solo hilo no es necesario utilizar un multiproceso porque en un solo proceso se puede ejecutar toda la función...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando su cliente pierde la conexion sucede la excepcion `socket.error`  en el servidor agregue esta excepción en su código para terminar la conexion

```
except socket.error:
        print "El cliente perdio la conexion inesperadamente"
        break
```

Entonces el codigo completo seria así

```
import socket  

s = socket.socket()   
s.bind(("192.168.1.94", 60))  
s.listen(1) 
print "server run"

sc, addr = s.accept()  

while True:

      try:
        recibido = sc.recv(1024)
        print recibido


      except socket.error:
        print "el cliente perdio la conexion"
        break


print "adios"  

sc.close() 
s.close()
```